# On the modulus of the product of the roots of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let D be the  open unit disc centered at the origin. Let $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n.$ Let $S=\{s|P(z)=s, z\in D\}.$  Let $\delta$ be any complex number lying outside $S.$ Then $P(z)-\delta\neq 0$ in $D.$   Is $|\delta- a_0|\geq |a_0|?$

If $|a_0|\leq 1$ it is a straightforward fact. Since $P(z)-\delta$ has all its zeros in $|z|\geq 1,$ the constant term of this polynomial $|a_0-\delta|\geq 1.$
But then $|a_0-\delta|\geq 1\geq |a_0|.$

But what about if $|a_0|>1?$

Comment: You could show how you handled the case $|a_0| \leq 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Added. Could you check if I am right?

Comment: Yes it is correct. I would like to re-open this question but I don't know if I will succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Take $D$ to be the open unit disk and $P(z)=10+z$. Take $\delta =1$. Then $\delta $ is not in $S$ but $|\delta-a_0|=|\delta-10|=9 <10=|a_0|$

Comment: Thanks. I am curious to know if I add an additional hypothesis of $|\delta|\geq \max_{|z|=1}||P(z)|$ then?

Comment: Still not true. In my example take $\delta =12$, for example. @mathlover

Comment: Thanks for the answer withe example